# Dúvida em relação ao protocolo https

Tags: apache, htaccess, http, https

Estou configurando um servidor Apache em Debian.

Ao acessar `https://.../index.php` pelo Chrome , tenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então minhas dúvidas são:

1. Para aparecer :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso necessariamente de um certificado pago, ou existe outro caminho?

2. Para não aparecer o alerta do browser, um caminho seria redirecionar
   o `https` para o `http`, é possível isso no Apache?

Comment: Eu não entendo do assunto, mas acho que não precisa necessariamente ser um certificado pago. Só precisa ser um certificado que o chrome reconheça como confiável.

Comment: Até onde sei, é possível obter certificados reconhecidos free através do https://letsencrypt.org.

Comment: @LINQ não basta ter um certificado, tem que ser um certificado dado por uma autoridade reconhecida pelo Google para o caso do Chrome.

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu quis dizer, @Renan.

Comment: Aperte F12 e dê uma olhada no Console, pode ser falta de certificado como também pode ser algum resource em HTTP e não HTTPS inserido no corpo da página.

Answer (score 2):

Cada navegador diferente possui uma lista dos certificados em que confia. Em geral, todos os certificados pagos são considerados confiáveis pelos principais navegadores. Já para os certificados gratuitos, você terá variações.

O mais conhecido dos certificadores gratuitos deve ser o Let's Encrypt. Eles têm [uma página na qual listam quais navegadores confiam em seu certificado](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/).

Note que a maioria dos navegadores e outros softwares confia neles. Apenas poucos players grandes no mercado não têm confiança (como o Windows Live Mail).

Já para mudar o protocolo de acesso à sua página, é sim possível fazer, de forma bem simples. Não sou especialista em Apache mas se com .htaccess ou similar você puder fazer um redirecionamento server-side, isso já é suficiente. Note apenas que, sem https, todo o tráfego ao seu site pode ser lido por intermediários.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um certificado gratuito, conheça:
[Let’s Encrypt is a free, automated, and open Certificate Authority](https://letsencrypt.org/)

**Instalar**
[Install Let’s Encrypt to Create SSL Certificates](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates)

**Configurar para o Apache**
[SSL Certificates with Apache on Debian & Ubuntu](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-debian-ubuntu)

**Redirecionamento HTTPS para HTTP (.htaccess)**

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Creio que se tem um tempo para instalar e configurar um certificado é melhor do que usar o redirecionamento de https para http.